# How to over ride the folder in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-attribute, magento-enterprise-2

I need some help.

How to override the magento2 enterprise edition folder to **app/design** theme folder "`module-customer-custom-attributes`".

Anyone, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can override this module functionality as you do for other community modules using dependency injection.

Create your **Package** and add module i.e `VendorName/ModuleName` and override this class: module classe(s) `CustomerCustomAttributes`

> NOTE: you have to `composer-update` and push on the server in order to get it work. without `composer-update`, your extension will not work.

Updated :

to override template files use this :

```
ThemeVendor/ThemeName/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates
```

Comment: I need just override the phtml file to the theme folder. I change the folder like Magento_Customer_Custom_Attributes but it's not working

Comment: i have updated answer with template folder naming convention